# Emphasis vs. Negation in Vulcan Language

Tags: constructed-language, negation

So according to this, https://kirshara.wordpress.com/vulcan-language/, *ri* in Vulcan is similar to "not". It gives an example:

> *Ri bolau nash-veh masu.* I do not need water.

It also says *ri* can be used to add emphasis to the word following it. It gives an example of this

> *Ri bolau sa-veh masu.* He does **not** need water

My question is, why did the creators of Vulcan(mostly Okrand and Vulcan fans) make it like this? Wouldn't here be some ambiguity with whether or not there is emphasis vs. solely negation between these two examples? Is there any non-constructed languages where this type of ambiguity exists?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you’re misreading it. The writer is saying that _ri_ negates the immediately following word, in other words, it can go anywhere in the sentence, negating different parts. In English, we’d use emphasis (*I* don’t need water, I don’t *need* water, I don’t need _water_), but in Vulcan you would instead just place the negation accordingly (not-I need water, I not-need water, I need not-water) to get the same meaning across.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That would make a good answer!

Comment: This would also be a perfect question for [conlang.se]